# Geometric meaning of Catlin multi types

Tags: reference-request, several-complex-variables

Can someone working in the area of several complex variables explain the geometric idea behind the Catlin multitype. I have seen the technical definition, but unable to grasp the idea behind this.

Also if someone can give references to study it further, it will be very helpful.

Comment: This seems too broad.  I think that a more focussed question would be better.